# How to create custom properties keypress event in propertygrid using vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need a coding for keypressevent in particular properties from the property grid.

It is possible to create an event for these(PropertyGrid Properties) properties?

(or)

How to create custom events for custom properties?

Comment: Please check [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers) link.

Answer (score 0):

There's a PropertyValueChanged event you can listen to.  The event args should have some info on what property got changed and what the value is.